# count number of all comments by a user on different (non-repeated) posts

Tags: comments, sql

I thank you in advance for your help. I am using Wordpress for about 2 years, but always avoiding SQL inside my scripts and looking for built-in functions to perform my goals.

To count the comments submitted by a specific user with `$user->ID` as id, I didn't find a built-in way, so I am using:

```
 global $wpdb;

        $count = $wpdb->get_var(
          'SELECT COUNT( comment_id ) FROM '. $wpdb->comments .'
          WHERE user_id = '.$user->ID.'
          AND comment_approved = "1"
          AND comment_type NOT IN ("pingback", "trackback" )'
        );
```

Actually my goal is to count number of all comments by a user on different posts. In other words, if a user commented 2 or more times on the same post, then only increment  the `$count` variable by one .

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of posts the user commented on, you can try:

```
global $wpdb;

$sql = 'SELECT COUNT( comment_ID ) FROM ' . $wpdb->comments . '  
        WHERE user_id = %d 
        AND comment_approved = "1"
        AND comment_type NOT IN ("pingback", "trackback" )
        GROUP by comment_post_ID';

$count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $user->ID ) );
```

where we group by the post ID.

Comment: Yes it is exactly like counting the number of posts the user commented on. Your fist sentence is simple and adress the issue directly.  I feel myself stupid. Thank you. I will test and come back here to give feedback.